# Baseline alignment in RelativeLayout does not work for RadioGroup

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout with a label and a RadioGroup, and I would like baseline of the label and the RadioButton children of the RadioGroup to be aligned. The code I have is:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/hi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hi"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hi"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/hi">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="There"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

What I get, instead, is that top of RadioGroup is aligned to baseline of the label, like so:

[image]

How do I get the behavior I want? I definitely don't want any hardcoded margins, or center alignment, I would like to align baselines.

It seems that View.getBaseline should report position of baseline relative to top of a view, and the behavior I see can be explained if that method returns 0 for RadioGroup. In fact, neither RadioGroup, nor its base class, LinearLayout, appear to define that method. But maybe, I have overlooked something.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. It turns out, you simply need to add two attributes. Consider the first version. It does NOT work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thomaskuenneth.temperatureconverter.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="42.0" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tempSrc"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/input"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/srcCelsius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="°C" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/srcFahrenheit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="°F" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/srcKelvin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="K" />

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result very much resembles the screenshot in the question.

[image: RadioButtons are not baseline-aligned]

Now, please put the following lines...

```
    android:baselineAlignedChildIndex="0"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
```

... inside the `<RadioGroup />`tag.

Now, it will look like this:

[image]

Neatly baseline-aligned...